# Drupal View Ticker module CSS

Tags: html, css, drupal, view, block

I can't seem to edit the CSS correctly for a block that holds content for the Views Ticker module

Here is what I have:

```
#block-views-rotating-news-block{
border:#F00 thin dotted;
float:left;
    left:0%;
        width:30%;

}
```

[image]

The content should be IN the block

If I leave the width variable out:

```
#block-views-rotating-news-block{
    border:#F00 thin dotted;
    float:left;
        left:0%;

}
```

I get this: [image]

Which is what I am looking for but I want to make sure the block is smaller aka I can set the width . Basically I want to define the width, but can not with out the block looking crazy. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want for that "content" to automatically set its width according to the text? Or you have a default given value?. Also, please give the code for the "link" style.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to change the width is the views.ticker.scroller style sheet i the views ticker module. No wonder why I couldn't overwrite the width.